# How to securely access my drive photos for specific users?

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-drive-api

**Aim**

My app should display photos in my drive `photos/` folder.

**Restriction**

There should be a way to allow specific users. Like those whom I shared my drive folder or restriction by any other means. Not all had the app should access it.

**Questions**

Do I need to enable Google credential for that?

When building credential it shows that `Application data cannot be accessed securely from Android. Please consider selecting another platform.`

[image]

Is drive and spreadsheet API disallowing this so they cannot be used as databases?

I want to use google drive as back-end as all the uploading and deleting facilities for clients are already there.